# Configurate x-axis by MaxNLocator Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I want to use MaxNLocator function to change the x-axis ticks because it is too crowded. However, it doesn't works. May I know what is the problem?

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

tickers = 'MP'

dateToday = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# Only get the adjusted close.
tickers_data = data.DataReader(tickers,
                       start='', 
                       end=dateToday, 
                       data_source='yahoo')[["Adj Close", "Volume"]][-250:]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
# sns.set_style("darkgrid")

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

sns.barplot(x=tickers_data.index.strftime('%d/%-m'), y=tickers_data['Volume'], color='#73a9d1')
plt.MaxNLocator(10)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.title(tickers)

axes2=plt.twinx()
axes2.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime('%d/%-m'), tickers_data['Adj Close'], color='b', linewidth=0.5)
axes2.set_ylabel('Price')
```

output:
[image]

Another plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

ax = sns.barplot(x=returns.index.strftime('%d/%-m'), y=returns['Adj Close'], color='#73a9d1')

plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tic.MaxNLocator(nbins=60))
plt.title('returns')
```

Answer (score 1):

Import `matplotlib.ticker` and Use it in `axes2`

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

tickers = 'MP'

dateToday = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# Only get the adjusted close.
tickers_data = data.DataReader(tickers,
                       start='', 
                       end=dateToday, 
                       data_source='yahoo')[["Adj Close", "Volume"]][-250:]

import matplotlib.ticker as tic # Imported Ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
# sns.set_style("darkgrid")

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

sns.barplot(x=tickers_data.index.strftime('%d/%-m'), y=tickers_data['Volume'], color='#73a9d1')
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.title(tickers)

axes2=plt.twinx()
axes2.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime('%d/%-m'), tickers_data['Adj Close'], color='b', linewidth=0.5)
axes2.xaxis.set_major_locator(tic.MaxNLocator(nbins=10)) #Added Here
axes2.set_ylabel('Price')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, there has a viewing problem, it doesnt shows the first and last two digits. May I know how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain more? which digits?

Comment: Hello. As the attached pic, first 2 digits and last 3 digits on x-axis is missing

Comment: You mean ticks? Do you have data available for that dates?

Comment: set limits using `plt.xlim([0,len(tickers_data)-1])`

Comment: Hello. I just use the same method to change the x-axis. It can show my desire ticks on x-axis. It works but the values on x-axis is wrong. I set nbins = 60, it just shows the first 60 days of value on x-axis not the whole timeframe. Sorry I have too many questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231645/discussion-between-zalak-bhalani-and-janicewww).